# Sobrepor colunas/linha

Tags: firemonkey

Estou a procuração de uma solução para manipular um `listbox`.

Meu cenário é esse:

Tenho um `listbox` com 5 Itens

```
LisboxItem1
LisboxItem2
LisboxItem3
LisboxItem4
LisboxItem5
```

Quando eu arrastar o `LisboxItem5` e soltar em cima do `LisboxItem1` eles trocam de lugar.

Essa solução teria que se aplicar no `Firemonkey`, no *Windows* funciona mas pra `Android` não.